# Free text in a dataframe merging and making it in continuous flow for every row

Tags: r

In a dataframe I have 2 columns with free text and I would like to merge them to one. I use `cbind(df$col1,df#col2)` or `rbind(df$col1,df#col2)` and I take a merged df but with number.

What can I do to merge them?

Also in the text there are many spaces like this:

```
something here

another line here
and we are here


but we also have this
```

and I would like to make it to be a continuous from like this:

```
something here another line here and we are here but we also have this
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: In that case, use `paste` with `collapse= " "`

Comment: @akrun thank it works for the merge. Any hint for the continuous flow of text?

Comment: Suppose you have many lines, then the `paste` will convert it to a single line

Comment: @akrun I think the paste makes it a whole text paste(df$col1,df$col2,collapse= " ") and I would like to merge every row for example I have 2 columns with 14 rows and in merge 1 col with 14 rows

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear from your example

Comment: not optimal but perhaps this: `apply(df,1,function(x) paste(df$col1,df$col2))[,1]`

Comment: @timfaber it worked for me the `as.data.frame(apply(df,1,function(x) paste(df$col1,df$col2))[,1)`